# How to ensure alarm fires even if app killed by system

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have application whose major functionality depend on alarm but alarm sometimes fired sometimes not, i red about it its says because system kills your app before alarm fires, how can i ensure alarm should fire even after application killed, here is how I'm setting alarm

```
 public static void setEndAlarm(){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  MyApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
    time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, SharedPrefUtils.getEndHour(MyApplication.getContext()));
    time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, SharedPrefUtils.getEndMin(MyApplication.getContext()));
    time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), endPendingIntent(MyApplication.getContext()));
}

private static PendingIntent endPendingIntent(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClsEndBroadcastReciever.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 02, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    return pendingIntent;
}
```

and the getting context like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}
}
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class ClsEndBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new 
 FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));

    dispatcher.cancel("notification");
    Toast.makeText(context, "End Time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reliably do this without system permissions.

Trying using IntentService and START_STICKY (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to ensure that the app does not get killed.

Comment: I think services are also killed, is that true

Comment: Yes in some device like oppp,vivo and many similar Android custom device, if you remove app from task bar(Swipe to clear) then that app will go to force stop that makes your  all service to be killed.

Comment: So how can I ensure reliability in my application

Comment: I think what you're actually trying to do is difficult and even OEMs need permission from Google. If you think about it in a user perspective, an app being kept alive consumes battery and could be annoying. With that being said, look into https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html or using GCM with SyncAdapter. A lot of applications that require background sync or alarms while the application is dead can only use these methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify your `BroadcastReceiver` in `Manifest` then it will be called even if your app is not active write now.

**Manifest**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Activities and Services -->

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver"/>

</application>
```

**AlarmBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // do what you want to do here.
        // if the work load is heavy then launch service for it here

    }
}
```

Comment: Its in the manifest, the problem is that alarm sometimes fires sometimes not

Comment: @blackHawk then can you post the code to show us how you set alarm?

Comment: its happening like this alarm firing every day after 5,6 days if application is not opened it does not fires, and if application open its fires as usual again

Comment: Do you have your Receiver class as a separate class? You should also not register receiver anywhere in code. It is already done when you included it in manifest

Comment: Yes its in separate class